# Replacing Fencing with Gaps Because of Erosion

Tags: fence

I will be replacing my 6ft fencing around the perimeter of my backyard, and there are several gaps where it appears the ground washed away portions to cause spacing between the ground and the bottom of the fencing. Is it a bad idea to purchase taller fence boards and to dig these fence boarding into the ground instead of allowing a gap at the bottom of the fence? I am a new homeowner, so I apologize for my ignorance in advance, but I am trying to find a way to keep the top of the fencing even across the top, but to also cover the gaps at the bottom, which are at different levels across the entirety of the fence placement. The fencing is in need of replacement, but I wanted to plan it out in advance before I start replacing sections.

Comment: I doubt it was the ground that did that. Probably you have inadequate drainage in case of storm or heavy rain. It's probably best to sort that out. The erosion is only going to continue otherwise... and you'll find your unequal fence inadequate again soon enough.

Comment: Are you sure it is erosion and not critters digging underneath the fence?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and purchase the longer fence boards but do not bury the lower ends in the ground. The boards will just rot faster if you poke then into the soil.  Instead cut each board to length as the fence is being built.

You can stretch a string between the posts for each section to be used to guide the top of the boards for that section. Then when you are ready for each board set it in place just resting on the ground and mark its length with a carpenter pencil at the string. (Note that if the fence boards are the dog eared style turn it upside down for marking so that you are cutting off the bottom).